# Angular JS Multi-template application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view

I'm new to Angular JS and I'm encountering some architecture problems while creating a multi-template website.

I have 2 main different templates:

1. Home page (login form on a fullscreen image)
2. A dashboard (with a sidebar and a content section where to show different wiev: contact, analytics, etc...)

For the dashboard I solved with ng-wiew and the routerProvider.

Like in the official documentation tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Concerning the Homepage I can't understand Angular JS logic...
Can I manange it just adding a Homecontroller? (in that case how does it work for meta and title page and so on?)

Or I need to build two separated app...

I'm confused and searching on Google didn't help me that much

Someone can explain me the best practices in case like mine ?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at uiRouter https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It's definitely what I need, but I've noticed this disclaimer: "Consider using it in production applications only if you're comfortable following a changelog and updating your usage accordingly." Aren't there angular "native" solutions to this problematique?

Comment: afaik this is the best solution

Comment: @user3154898, unfortunately at the moment Angular does not natively support multi-template. uiRouter is pretty damn good. Regarding the disclaimer, just don't update the uiRouter version until you need to do so!

Comment: Ok, I go for UI-router. It seems really powerfull. Thanks for the help.